# webrtc - In firefox beta version giving InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Local descriptions must have a=mid attributes error

Tags: webrtc

WEBRTC - while setting answer into setLocalDescription getting below error in firefox beta version .63

this.soc.setLocalDescription(answer, function(){}, function(error){ co.handleAnswerLoacalDescError(error); } );

SWRTCAnswerPConn.prototype.handleAnswerLoacalDescError = function (error) {
    console.log("error SWRTCAnswerPConn.prototype.handleAnswerLoacalDescError "+error);
}

Below one is the local sdp

```
"v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-63.0 6779639364423913043 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\n
 a=ice-options:trickle\r\n
 a=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 0\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n
 a=sendrecv\r\n
 a=ice-pwd:0c25b6011567fa002a87fw6d36d0c32e\r\n
 a=ice-ufrag:9cba9881\r\n
 a=msid:{342671bf-c92f-4d7e-add6-37228fcaffc4} {6876af26-691b-4beb-9fed-a18e27ea0fe0}\r\n
 a=rtcp-mux\r\n
 a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n
 a=setup:active\r\n
 a=ssrc:127692948 cname:{f7d3d74d-86e0-4a27-a143-79f4703d32cf}\r\n"
```

*

> ***InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Local descriptions must have a=mid attributes***

*

Please, anyone, help to resolve this issue.

Comment: it would be helpful to show the answer sdp.

Comment: "v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-63.0 6779639364423913043 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\n
     a=ice-options:trickle\r\n
     a=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 0\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\n
     a=sendrecv\r\n
     a=ice-pwd:0c25b6011567fa002a87fw6d36d0c32e\r\n
     a=ice-ufrag:9cba9881\r\n
     a=msid:{342671bf-c92f-4d7e-add6-37228fcaffc4} {6876af26-691b-4beb-9fed-a18e27ea0fe0}\r\n
     a=rtcp-mux\r\n
     a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\n
     a=setup:active\r\n
     a=ssrc:127692948 cname:{f7d3d74d-86e0-4a27-a143-79f4703d32cf}\r\n"

Comment: Please give quick reply, we need urgent fix for it

Comment: The other side of your call is sending SDP without a=mid lines. This is not per spec, even though Firefox reaction is good. The Firefox folks are tracking a bug for this here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1495569

Comment: After i have added a=mid:0 attribute in SDP manually,now SDP setting properly in localDescription i.e we are not getting InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Local descriptions must have a=mid attributes exception, but we are not getting voice properly i have verified webrtc internals there ICE Status is coming as Failed

Comment: v=0\r\no=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-63.0 88154467 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E8:F3:1E:7B:9C:4B:5D:66:9E:87:2A:DB:BC:6D:8E:E6:A3:81:72:D7:13:CE:FA:FE:66:AA:60:9A:7F:EF:62:9A\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 0\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ice-pwd:e2c2d40edcacdc322dfe78d504000b76\r\na=ice-ufrag:fff887a6\r\na=mid:0\r\na=msid:{1ed0b2a3-9fb9-4307-a574-193654754333} {e3b2879c-a527-444a-b8df-9320fab14e92}\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=setup:active\r\na=ssrc:2007682237 cname:{51592-9a1f-4bda-891e-89fc61922}\r\n